# How to send real time progress to webclient using Spring webflux?

Tags: java, flux, spring-webflux, server-sent-events

I have a rest api which call multiple micro services. As the operation is long, I am trying to make it reactive with real time reporting of progress to let the webclient know which steps is being executed. How should I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Server Sent Events.  This means, if your client can do HTTP/2 (which `WebClient` should), you return a `Flux<YourStatus>`, and the client will be able to read and react to it.
Haven't tried this myself, yet, but that's what the documentation said.  Maybe that pointer helps you...